# Nagios is not sorting the hosts in descending order by default

Tags: nagios

We have a nagios server which is monitoring nearly 100 servers. In these 100 servers nearly 90 servers are in descending order and remaining 10 servers are following ascending order When I click on HOSTS tab. Please let me know how to fix this issue. If I click on the hosts tab,it should show the hosts in descending order.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is case sensitive so upper case hosts will be listed before lower case. Not sure if this is your issue but worth considering